# Python MySql Insert not working

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python MySQL API to connect to Mysql database from python program. I am facing a problem from few days. I am unable to insert records into the database and dont know whats the reason. Here is the way i connect and insert records into the database.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","padmaramulu","pdfsearch" )
cursor = db.cursor()
#cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documents (docid INT NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY(docid),docname CHAR(30)) engine=innodb""")
temp = "hello";number = 2;
cursor.execute( 'insert into documents(docid,docname) values("%d","%s")' % (number,temp) )
db.close()
```

Why is it so?

Comment: You should mark the answer that solved your problem. The person who wrote that answer will get well-deserved bonus points, and readers will instantly now that the solution has been applied and works.

Answer (score 165):

Before closing the connection, you should add `db.commit()`.

Comment: alternatively you can use db.autocommit(True) at the begning of your script. since auto commit is disabled for MySQLdb starting with 1.2.0

Comment: @SRC whilst your solution **does** work, it is only used when developing. In production, you should *always* manage your own transactions

Comment: Thank you sir! I was scratching my head until I read this. Much appreciated!

Comment: db.autocommit(True) worked for me but db.commit did not...  until... i realised that I had typed db.commit and not db.commit()  I FORGOT THE BRACKETS AT THE END - such a fool I am

Comment: note: add `.commit()` to the original db connection not the cursor

Answer (score 6):

if you are using **InnoDB** engine in MySQL you should add

```
db.commit()
```

else change your MySQL engine into **MyISAM** no need to change anything in code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone got same problem, and maybe this helpful,,

Any 2 option :

a. for who using MySqldb :

```
db.commit()
```

b. for who using Mysql Connector :

```
cnx.commit()
```

Add this code before close the db or Mysql Connector :

a. sample : ([Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-python))

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

# Obtain connection string information from the portal
config = {
  'host':'<mydemoserver>.mysql.database.azure.com',
  'user':'<myadmin>@<mydemoserver>',
  'password':'<mypassword>',
  'database':'<mydatabase>',
  'client_flags': [ClientFlag.SSL],
  'ssl_cert': '/var/wwww/html/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem'
}

# Construct connection string
try:
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  # Drop previous table of same name if one exists
  cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory;")
  print("Finished dropping table (if existed).")

  # Create table
  cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE inventory (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), quantity INTEGER);")
  print("Finished creating table.")

  # Insert some data into table
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (%s, %s);", ("banana", 150))
  print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (%s, %s);", ("orange", 154))
  print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (%s, %s);", ("apple", 100))
  print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")

  # Cleanup
  conn.commit()
  cursor.close()
  conn.close()
  print("Done.")
```

b. sample : ([Dev Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html))

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='employees')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

tomorrow = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)

add_employee = ("INSERT INTO employees "
               "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
add_salary = ("INSERT INTO salaries "
              "(emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date) "
              "VALUES (%(emp_no)s, %(salary)s, %(from_date)s, %(to_date)s)")

data_employee = ('Geert', 'Vanderkelen', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

# Insert new employee
cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
emp_no = cursor.lastrowid

# Insert salary information
data_salary = {
  'emp_no': emp_no,
  'salary': 50000,
  'from_date': tomorrow,
  'to_date': date(9999, 1, 1),
}
cursor.execute(add_salary, data_salary)

# Make sure data is committed to the database
cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be fixed

```
cursor.execute( 'insert into documents(docid,docname) values(%d, %s)', (number,temp) )
```

and then You should add `db.commit()` before you close database connection.

Answer (score 0):

You may set python to autocommit changes in your database like this:

````py
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","padmaramulu","pdfsearch, autocommit=True")```
````