# mysql.connector doesn' t insert with python command, but manually the query works

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-connector

So after my research on stackoverflow didn't bring me any further here ist my code (I cannot post the exact code , because this is a problem I have at work) and problem:

```
 import mysql.connector
 .    
 .
 .
 cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)
 cursor = cnx.cursor()

 for-loop:
     if condition:
          cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (the_columns) VALUES (%s)", (my_values))
          cnx.commit()
```

I tried to insert manually already and it worked, but somehow my python code won't do the insert.

The manual insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,...,column7) VALUES (string1,....,string6, now())
```

I have no error message, I can only look into the database and see that the new valiues aren't there.
Did anyone else face this problem? Can anyone suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: The issue was solved, there has been a problem because the previous dev had two instances with the same name and it wasn't a msql error at all.

Comment: For future comers, add `cursor.commit()` before closing the connection `cnx.close()`, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027346/18131146) with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because you dont have to put your variable between "(" ")" ?
Did you tried to put the value directly inside the sql, then instead of the variable containing it?
What do you mean by "manually"?

Anyway, you should put all your variables in an array, before passing this array as the second argument:

```
query = (
  "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
data = (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', datetime.date(2012, 3, 23))
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

EDIT: I just checked, thats the main exemple if you google your problem... wait did you searched for this a little bit? That's the best wait to learn dude: search by yourself before asking for help.

Comment: yes, I tried and meant that by manually. No the parantheses are not the problem, it worked before with the exact same allignment. And I tried to remove them, which has thrown an Syntax Error.

Comment: ok, try to put your variable in a data array like the exemple (Edited sorry >.>)

Comment: I tried that already and I googled for one hour and it didn't work also. why else would I ask on stackoverflow?

Comment: can you edit and show the "manual" way you tried please? (because many engineers lose their time on stackOverflow, and they have the answer to absolutely everything, that's why)

Answer (score 0):

Try turning your format variables into a tuple. If this does not work. Try creating the query as a variable seperately and printing it out and running it in your sql console directly. You might get more meaningful errors.

```
 cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)
 cursor = cnx.cursor()

 for-loop:
     if condition:
         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (the_columns) VALUES (%s)", (my_values,))
         cnx.commit()
```

OR

```
 cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)
 cursor = cnx.cursor()

 for-loop:
     if condition:
         sql = "INSERT INTO table ({}) VALUES ({})".format(the_columns,my_values)
         print(sql)
         cursor.execute(sql)
         cnx.commit()
```