# GoDaddy MySQL Table not receiving my Insert/Update request

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm, sql-update, sql-insert

I’m writing (using pycharm) to a database with multiple tables (I didn’t create this database, it was done by another developer).

Table 1 & 2, I can write to (Insert, Update, etc),
Table 3 is not receiving my commands from my pycharm (there are no error msgs on pycharm’s logs or sentry.io), but the auto increment value increases, AND, if i write to it from heidisql, it works!

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="###.###.##.##",
  user="##########",
  passwd="##########",
  database='########',

)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO user (id, mobile, store_id, register_date, deleted_date) VALUES (NULL, '8008008000', '200', '0', '0')")
```

Answer (score 1):

After research, it is discovered that Table 1 & 2 use MyISAM which the transactions to them autocommits. As for table 3, it uses InnoDb which for some reason, needs to end with mydb.commit() to process the transaction.

Source: [Python MySql Insert not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027271/python-mysql-insert-not-working)